# Creating a new column by using another column values

Tags: r, decimal, rows, names

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(3.132324,12.3439085,3.34343,5.1239048,6.34323,3.342334,9.342343,134.132433,13.1234323,23.34323))
```

Now, I want to use the A values to create a new column B that's based on the value one row below A. Like this:

```
      A          B
1    3.132324  12.343908
2   12.343908   3.343430
3    3.343430   5.123905
4    5.123905   6.343230
5    6.343230   3.342334
6    3.342334   9.342343
7    9.342343 134.132433
8  134.132433  13.123432
9   13.123432  23.343230
10  23.343230         NA
```

I've tried using a code like this `data$B <- c(tail(data$A, -1), NA))`, but I'm getting incorrect number of decimals (e.g. values with 6 decimal points turn into 5 decimal points). I want B values to follow **exactly** the A values, which includes decimal points.

How do I do this?

Update

This shows the problem I have in my actual dataset whereby the B becomes rounded when I use the mutate() function as @akrun suggests below.

```
     A        B
1  7.933333 16.01667
2 16.016667 24.53333
3 24.533333 34.70000
4 34.700000       NA
```

Comment: Your code works for me without rounding issues

Comment: I think it is a print formatting issue.  If you check `tibble(A = c(7.933333, 16.016667, 24.533333, 34.700000), B = lead(A)) %>% as.data.frame -> out;out$B[-nrow(out)] == out$A[-1]#
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: @akrun. Yes, you're right! Thank you. Looks like it was just a printing issue and not a problem with the values.

Comment: @JoshuaMire I've tried it. It got a bit complicated for my actual dataset because I need to nest the for loop inside another for loop.

Comment: @Drew If you wanted to change the settings, check the options to print the tibble output and specify the number of decimal points to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lead` with `mutate` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     mutate(B = lead(A))
#           A          B
#1    3.132324  12.343908
#2   12.343908   3.343430
#3    3.343430   5.123905
#4    5.123905   6.343230
#5    6.343230   3.342334
#6    3.342334   9.342343
#7    9.342343 134.132433
#8  134.132433  13.123432
#9   13.123432  23.343230
#10  23.343230         NA
```

---

Based on the OP's code, let's try on a `list`

```
slotfinal <- list(data, data)
for(i in seq_along(slotfinal)) slotfinal[[i]] <- slotfinal[[i]] %>%
             mutate(B = lead(A))

slotfinal
#[[1]]
#            A          B
#1    3.132324  12.343908
#2   12.343908   3.343430
#3    3.343430   5.123905
#4    5.123905   6.343230
#5    6.343230   3.342334
#6    3.342334   9.342343
#7    9.342343 134.132433
#8  134.132433  13.123432
#9   13.123432  23.343230
#10  23.343230         NA

#[[2]]
#            A          B
#1    3.132324  12.343908
#2   12.343908   3.343430
#3    3.343430   5.123905
#4    5.123905   6.343230
#5    6.343230   3.342334
#6    3.342334   9.342343
#7    9.342343 134.132433
#8  134.132433  13.123432
#9   13.123432  23.343230
#10  23.343230         NA
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I've tried this before, but for me, I'm still getting the issue of the automatic conversion of 6point decimals into 5. This may be because I am applying the mutate() function inside a **for loop** to a list of dataframes with all varying decimal points.

Comment: @Drew can you show your actual code..   If you check this example, it is a single dataset and the `mutate` with the `lead` values is creating a column from that dataset and not from a different dataset.  It would be interesting to check your code

Comment: `for(i in 1:length(slotfinal)){
  slotfinal[[i]] %>% mutate(Spin.next = lead(Time.of.bet))
}`

Comment: @Drew I tried your code updated.  But, it is still not showing the issue you raised

Comment: @Drew Can you update with `dput` of the example so that I get the correct structure